# Server 2008 Permissions

Tags: windows-server-2008, permissions

Sorry if this is a silly question.

In server 2008, it is impossible for a user with administrator privileges to run things as an administrator without explicitly commanding it (right click->run as administrator, or properties->always run as administrator).  This is not working for us for many reasons.  Is there anyway to set everything to run as administrator by default?

Comment: install windows 95?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

[**Turn off UAC**](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc709691%28WS.10%29.aspx#BKMK_S3) (or disable Admin Approval Mode).

(Note: doing this voids any warranty I may give you as to the security of your server)

Comment: Indeed, if the reason it's "not working for you" is on of the standard variants on being annoyed at having to click extra things, then **don't turn it off**.

Comment: Even with UNC turned off we still must explicitly command executable to run in administrator mode.

Comment: Disable Admin Approval mode

Comment: it looks as if UAC was not actually off and the machines needed a reboot for the setting to take effect.  Though disabling admin approval is an excellent alternative.

Answer (score 0):

You can try disable Admin Approval Mode.

Click Start, click All Programs, click Accessories, click Run, type secpol.msc in the Open box, and then click OK.

From the Local Security Settings console tree, double-click Local Policies, and then double-click Security Options.

Scroll down and double-click User Account Control: Run all administrators in Admin Approval Mode.

Select the Disabled option, and then click OK.